# EACCES: permission denied in VS Code MAC

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I change any file, the system will deny me access. What's going on?
How do I properly set permissions on Mac?

[image]

Answer (score 174):

It is generally not a good idea to run VS Code as sudo. Instead change the permission for the directory.

You can change the ownership of the directory so that you can open it without needing root privileges.

```
$ sudo chown -R <user-name> <directory-name>
```

Comment: @MertA.Can you elaborate on what you mean by "sudo command did not work on terminal"?

Comment: This works. Specifying only the user name while in the directory did not work, but navigating to the parent and specifying the target directory did.

Comment: This is just a hint for typing your "directory-name" quickly: dragging your target folder from Finder to Terminal :)

Comment: make sure you are not in the directory it self, but it's parent.

Comment: Doesn't work either. I get "permission denied, mkdir"

Answer (score 51):

First, take note of the current permissions of all files and folders by issuing the command:

```
ls -lR <project_dir_name> > old_permissions.txt
```

which will save the output of the command `ls -l <project_dir_name>` to the file `old_permissions.txt` in the current directory.

If you have no idea of how permissions work and what the results of the previous command represent, please, have a look at https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-permissions.html and https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html.

At this point, to modify any of the files under `<project_dir_name>`, you can give full permission to all subfolders and files recursively by issuing the command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 <project_dir_name>
```

Note that you're responsible for the changes your perform!

After having saved the updates, you can reset the previous permission settings of the folders by looking at the old permissions saved in the file `old_permissions.txt`. You should set the permissions manually (unless you create e.g. a script to do it automatically using the info saved in `old_permissions.txt`).

**Note**: *it's probably a better idea to only modify the permissions of the specific files that you want to modify (and not of the whole folder).*

Comment: Chmod 777 is unsafe if you are on shared hosting.

Answer (score 26):

I managed to fix this on Mac while running this in Terminal

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/$(whoami)/.vscode`

hope this helps someone

Comment: Thank you! This helped me. What exactly is -R doing?

Comment: - R parameter is shorthand for the recursive option so it applies the current user as owner for all the files in the folder (see https://devconnected.com/how-to-chown-recursive-on-linux/)

Comment: "/Users/xxx/.vscode": no such file or directory

Answer (score 25):

Uninstall the code command from PATH in vscode and reinstall it.

1. Open the command pallete (command + shift + P), search "uninstall 'code'" and select the first option to uninstall.
2. Open the command pallete (command + shift + P), search "install 'code'" and click "Install 'code' command in PATCH

Comment: Woks in macOS Sonoma, thanks

Comment: Still works in MacOS Ventura 13.6

Answer (score 19):

None of the above solutions solved this issue for me, here's what finally worked:

`System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy (tab) > (scroll down to) Files and Folders > Select Desktop Folder`

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! I just installed it and I remembered it asked me some permission, and like a dumb**** I denied it 

Comment: This is the correct answer imo! Works in Sonoma too, though the settings app looks slightly different.

Comment: I had to grant Read & Write permissions to staff

Answer (score 12):

cd to the project directory and 
run `cd ..` to move back one folder
 run `sudo chmod -R 777 <project_dir_name>` 
it works for me vscode never asked me for password when saving my file again.

Comment: This isn't safe practice. You are opening up the file permissions to anyone. The loosest you should ever have to do is 775.

Comment: Thanks for pin-pointing that @AJStacy 775 is more secure.

Answer (score 10):

I found a fix. I simply uninstalled the code command from PATH in vscode and reinstalled. i.e open the command pallete, search "uninstall 'code' command in PATH" and select the first option to uninstall. Then do the same to install it back `"install 'code'..."`. Do same for installing too. That should fix it

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/129884

props to lazy-poet

Answer (score 8):

**Easy fix:**

1. In VSC press `cmd+shift+p`
2. Type `'uninstall code'`
3. Select `'uninstall code'`
4. Reinstall it again with `cmd+shift+p` and type `'install code'` and select `"install code"`.

Comment: Still have the issue when trying to delete the `node_modules` folder. Do you have an Idea on the reason why ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to fix permissions for the current user use `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.vscode/`.

- `$(whoami)` is a variable with the current user that's logged in
- `~` is a shorthand for the home directory of the current user

Comment: This command ran, now what is the next step?

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was problems with mixed permissions within `.git/objects` directory. Some of them been my user, some - surprisingly - root.

This helped:

```
cd: .git/objects
sudo chown -R username:usergroup *
```

If mismatch with permissions occur not only within git objects but whole repo, chown command can be executed in upper directory.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your project, double click on the app.js file and select 'Get info'. There will be an option of 'Sharing & Permission'. From there you can change access permissions for other users.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it turned out that the `VSCode` application was in the Downloads folder, and not in the Applications folder.

After I moved it to the Applications folder, I deleted the `/usr/local/bin/code` symlink. Then, I closed and re-opened `VSCode`, and hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and typed `code` which brought up `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` and successfully added code to the path!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I had error when I tried to create a new component. I just navigated to the path displayed in Finder. For me it was **ProjectFolder/src/**. So I did right click on "**src**" folder and selected "**Get Info**". In that change access to "Read&Write" for my user account. Thats it !!!

As you are trying to update a file, try to change access permission for that file (ie. **app.component.css**). If it didn't work try to change access for "**app**" folder.

**Note**: Changing the access of parent/super-parent folder won't work. So change the exact folder's access preferences.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution for me.

Open the Terminal and enter this command:

```
code --user-data-dir="./vscode-root"
```

This is for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Kindly mind your solution to this link where it explains why it is not one of the best practice to do so. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root) PS: As recommended by other users chown is the ideal way to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the folder
go to Get Info
sharing and permission on the bottom
unlock the lock
and press the 3 dots you will see a drop down
apply to enclosed items
make it happen, and try again

Answer (score 0):

Go to your terminal and input the command:

```
sudo "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron" ~/.bash_profile
```

It works for me.

However, according to the answers on the websites, it is not recommended to get super user permission when you launch the vs code. I am new to vs code as well so I don't know the right method to get permission.

Besides, on my mac, you will get only permission once when you type in the command and after you exit your vs code, you will not possess the permission if you open the vs code again. I am still working on it and try to fix.

But this answer should fix your problem.

Comment: You should never need to run a program using sudo unless it's a special edge case and even then you should question why it's necessary.  Fix the file permissions like Tin Nguyen suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution: You probably tried to save the file to "Macintosh Hd" which is the default place when you click on "Save as", so you can't just save a file to the computer inside itself, you have got to choose a directory, like you can save it to /Desktop or /users/your_username/... something like that. But saving to "Macintosh Hd" will always be unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are probably trying to access a project which is owned by a another user e.g. the user which is not currently logged in.

You need to login as that user to work on the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
sudo chown -R <username> ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code 
sudo chown -R <username> ~/.vscode/extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me. All you have to do is to;

1.Open your terminal in vscode and type:

```
sudo chown -R <username> 'path-to-your-project-folder'
```

2.Hit enter and you're sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution to this:

I changed my VS code permission for some stupid purposes (e.g. access to Mac font), and I cannot open it anymore via Application.

Below is what I did (suggested by GPT4):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code
```

It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I Fix this on my M1 mac using this command.

```
sudo chown -R <userName> *
```

This command will allow ownership to the user for all files.