# File permissions exception for Visual Studio Mac

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, visual-studio-mac, fluentftp

I run Visual Studio on Mac for developing `.NET Core`. I have problems with file permissions.

When I for example use `FluentFTP` to download a file:

```
client.DownloadFile("/Users/max/temp/download_folder", "remote/path");
```

I get the following error:

```
Access to the path '/Users/max/temp/download_folder' is denied.
```

Note that I've also got this error using `Path` and `Directory`.

I've confirmed that the paths are OK. I've tested to set `chmod 777 /Users/max/temp/`. I've also tried to place the file at `/var/tmp/`, where full file access is default.

I get the feeling that `Visual Studio` is not run with sufficient permissions. In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980338/eacces-permission-denied-in-vs-code-mac) a similar problem for Visual Studio Code is solved by setting `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/$(whoami)/.vscode`, but I can't find any dotfiles for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I passed a directory path, while the method wanted a file name path. The exception message could've been more informative. Hope that this answer can help someone in the future.