# Allow VS Code to read download files for Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, permissions

I messed up by denying vs code to read my "download files", however, I believe this is an issue found on mac's permission settings (in which I don't know where to find it). I say this because when I downloaded a firebase file (GoogleService-Info (2).plist) I am able to run it in Xcode but not in Vs Code. How can I allow Vs code to read all download files?
[image]

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question, see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65710222/5812524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple icon - system preferences - privacy

Select Files and Folders.

Select the checkbox below an app to allow it to access files and folders in that location.